# How to display Cimy extra fields in front side user profile page in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I installed the `CIMY User Extra Fields plugin` to add new custom fields in `the user profile`.

I added 1 custom field for gender to the user profile but it displays only in the admin panel user profile. How to display on the front side registered user profile page?

Have any one idea.. Please send me step by step because new in `WordPress`.

Answer (score 0):

Install and activate 'Theme My Login' plugin. This will do the trick for you.